# get() not working, errors do not follow documentation

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Adding a Firestore rule to ensure that users can only access their company's data. company is a field in their records in the users collection. The name of the collection is the same as company.

This is how I believe it should work, based on Firestore documentation. I did try some things that made more sense to me, like adding brackets, taking away the slashes the error message said was wrong, but got the same result.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if false;
    }

    match /{collectionName}/{document=**} {
      allow read: if get(databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.company == collectionName;
      }

  }
}
      }
```

The allow read if get(....line is line 22. 
This is the error message I got when I tried to publish the rule set..

```
 Line 22: Unexpected '$'.; Line 22: Missing 'match' keyword before path.; 
Line 22: Forward slash '/' found where identifier or binding expected.; 
Line 22: mismatched input '$' expecting {'{', '/', PATH_SEGMENT}; 
Line 22: Missing 'match' keyword before path.; 
Line 22: Forward slash '/' found where identifier or binding expected.; 
Line 22: mismatched input '$' expecting {'{', '/', PATH_SEGMENT}
```

To me, none of those errors make sense, because match is there, and everything else I just copied from the documentation...
for reference, here is the get() example from Firebase's documentation:

```
allow delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `/` at the start of the path you're passing to `get()` and you're calling `get` somewhere where `$(request.auth.uid)` isn't available. Based on the code you shared it's impossible to say more, so please edit your question to include the minimum, complete/standalone rules that are needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe it was that simple. Yes, it was just the missing ```/``` causing all of the problems.